# Including runfiles in a filegroup

Tags: node.js, bazel

Im new to Bazel.

I thought id start by trying to build a simple nodejs project, it uses babel to do some transforming as part of the build process, the issue im having is  I cant seem to find a way to get these transformed files into a filegroup.

Here's my BUILD file.

```
load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:defs.bzl", "nodejs_binary")
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/pkg:pkg.bzl", "pkg_tar")


 # Group all our initial code.
 filegroup(
     name = "src",
     srcs = [
        ".babelrc",
        "package.json",
        "//config:src",
        "//handlers:src",
        "//migrations:src",
        "//models:src",
        "//services:src",
        "//tasks:src",
        "@dependencies//:node_modules",
     ],
 )

 # Group all our generated code.
 filegroup(
    name = "out",
    srcs = [
        "//:babel:runfiles" ### ???
    ],
 )

 nodejs_binary(
 name         = "babel",
 entry_point  = "babel-cli/bin/babel.js",
 templated_args = [
    ".",
    "--ignore node_modules,test/,migrations/,babel_bin_loader.js",
    "-d out",
    "--source-maps=both",
    "--copy-files",
],
node_modules = "@nodejs_build_tools//:node_modules",
data = [
    "//:src",
]
)

pkg_tar(
    name = "build",
    strip_prefix = "/",
    package_dir = "/usr/src/app",
    srcs = ["//:out"],
    mode = "0755",
)
```

My issue is that im not sure how to reference the runfiles from my nodejs_binary rule.

https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/blob/master/internal/node/node.bzl#L130

Seems to indicate that there should be a :runfiles attribute or similar?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

So turns out that the correct way to do this appears to be by using a genrule to actually call the configured nodejs binary. Eg.

```
## Artifact Construction ##
genrule( 
    name = "construct_artifact",
    outs = ["artifact.tar"],
    cmd  = """./$(location babel)  . --ignore bazel- 
    out,node_modules,text/,migrations/ -d out/ --source-maps=both --copy-files && tar cvf $@ out/ """,
    srcs = [
        "//:src",
    ],
    tools = [
        "//:babel",
    ]
)
```